# Rank of the incidence matrix of a directed graph.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Can someone please help me prove that the rank of the incidence matrix of a 'simple' directed graph with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges is $n-1$? The nodes are labelled $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and the edges are labelled $\{1,2,...,m\}$.

The element $a_{ij}$ of the incidence matrix is determined in the following way,
$a_{ij}=0$ if the node $i$ is not on edge $j$.
$a_{ij}=-1$ if the edge $j$ ends on node $i$.
$a_{ij}=1$ if the edge $j$ starts on node $i$.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797082/81360) is related

Comment: Note that for a rank of $n-1$, you need the additional hypothesis that your graph is weakly connected.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(G,E)$ refer to our simple, directed graph. Let $(G',E')$ denote the corresponding undirected graph.

One proof is as follows: begin with the case where $G'$ is a tree, which can be handled in the manner described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3797182/81360).

Now, consider the case where $G'$ is any connected graph. We use the following facts:

- Every undirected connected graph has a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree),
- Every tree on $n$ nodes  has $n-1$ edges,
- Relabeling the nodes/edges (or equivalently, permuting the rows/columns of the incidence matrix) does not change the rank of the incidence matrix.

Relabel the edges of the graph so that the edges $1,\dots,n-1$ are the edges of our spanning tree. The first $n-1$ columns of the matrix form the incidence matrix of a tree, so these are linearly independent. It follows that the span of these $n-1$ columns is given by the subspace $S \subset \Bbb R^n$, defined by
$$
S = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n) : x_1 + \cdots + x_n = 0\}.
$$
Indeed, it suffices to observe that the span of these colums is a subspace of $S$ and that the dimension of the span is equal to that of $S$. Now, we see that the remaining columns of the incidence matrix are each elements of $S$. Thus, the column span of the *entire* incidence matrix of $G$ is $S$, which means that this incidence matrix has rank $n-1$.

Finally, consider the case of an arbitrary graph $G$. Let $G_1',\dots,G_k'$ denote the connected components of $G'$. Relabel the vertices so that the vertices of $G_1'$ come first, followed by the vertices of $G_2'$, and so forth. Similarly, relabel the edges so that the edges corresponding to $G_1'$ come first, followed by the edges of $G_2'$, and so forth.

I claim that the incidence matrix of $(G,E)$ (under this relabeling) has the block-diagonal form
$$
B = \pmatrix{B_1 \\ & B_2 \\ && \ddots \\ &&& B_k},
$$
where $B_j$ is the incidence matrix of $G_j$. Conclude that the rank of $B$ is the sum of the ranks of $B_1,\dots,B_k$, and is therefore given by $n - k$, where $k$ is the total number of connected components.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm not the OP but I posted the question you referred to. I'm wondering if this analysis can be extended to cases of weighted directed graphs, especially in cases where asymmetric (positive) edge weights exist, i.e., if the edge goes from $i$ to $j$ and $w_{ij} \neq w_{ji}$, in which case (let the edge be $k$) $A_{ik} = w_{ij}$ and $A_{jk} = -w_{ji}$. I drew some simple examples but it seems to me that the rank of the weighted incidence matrix is not $n-1$ but $n$, when the "asymmetrically weighted" edge is part of a cycle, otherwise the rank still $n-1$.

Comment: @user594147 I'm not sure. If you're interested, I recommend that you make a new post about that